# Accounting: Charging a Customer for a Service you had to Outsource

Tags: accounting

I run a horse boarding facility where customers pay a monthly rate for maintaining and care for the horse, as well as access to facilities such as indoor riding rings and trails. Some of the care and maintenance is not included in the boarding fee, and is paid for by the farm, but added to the invoice for the customer to reimburse. Such items include veterinarian and farrier visits as needed. We also charge a small handling fee for these services.

My question is how to account for the reimbursement. The handling fee is straight forward since it's clearly revenue. The reimbursement for the vet and farrier isn't a direct expense, so I'm not sure what accounts to credit and debit to differentiate a an expense passed onto the customer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your business model is to transparently pass on those veterinarian and farrier costs to your customers.  If you pay the veterinarian for their services, and seek reimbursement later, you are effectively loaning money to your customer because you've paid the vet bill that really was the responsibility of the horse owner.

One way to handle this in your accounts is to create an asset account called "Money owed to me by the owner of Silver Blaze" (I realise there is a possibility you may come up with a better name for this account).

- When you pay the vet's bill, your accounts should show money leaving your bank account (or your credit card account) and increasing the balance of your "*Money owed to me ...*" asset account.
- When your customer pays your invoice (which includes a line showing the vet costs to be reimbursed) some of the payment should be credited to the *Money owed to me ...* account, reducing the balance to (hopefully) zero.

You haven't specified the locality where this is taking place, or other relevant details of your business, so I don't know if this reimbursement will make you liable for GST (Goods and Services Tax) or VAT (Value Added Tax) or some locally-equivalent tax.

Please note that I'm not an accountant, but I'm providing an answer because no actual accountants have done so.